# usb device identification

Tags: python, controls, port, device

i am using python on ubuntu 9.04
say i have two usb devices connected to a single PC. how can i identify the devices in python code.....for example like

if usb port id == A
     write data to device 1
if usb port id == B
     write data to device 2

any ideas....

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried [pyUsb](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb)?
Install using:

```sh
pip install pyusb
```

Here a snippet of what you can do:

```python
import usb
busses = usb.busses()
for bus in busses:
    devices = bus.devices
    for dev in devices:
        print("Device:", dev.filename)
        print("  idVendor: %d (0x%04x)" % (dev.idVendor, dev.idVendor))
        print("  idProduct: %d (0x%04x)" % (dev.idProduct, dev.idProduct))
```

[Here](https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst) a good tutorial of pyUsb.

For more documentation, use Python interactive mode with `dir()` and `help()`.

Comment: i have used the above code in a terminal window...it returns an error "object has no attribute devices"
can you refer me to some tutorial that might help...or elaborate this module usb

Comment: Code is working for me on Osx with Python 2.6 and pyUsb installed with port.
What is your platform\Python version?

Comment: i have installed pyusb now and run the sample usbenum.py (your mentioned code seems pretty similar)....i have 3 usb port on my PC but the results show 6 outputs to dev.filename..they are numbers like 001 or 005 etc....
and they changed when i plugged in devices...(i am no good with the usb standards)....i just want to identify each device/port...
what parameter in the example would help me....

Comment: You can talk with a device just knowing its idVendor/idProduct and regardless of which port it is connected.

Comment: on windows I get no output

Answer (score 5):

[@systempuntoout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487095/4298200) is nice but today I have found an easier way to find or iterate over all devices: `usb.core.find(find_all=True)`

Following with your example:

```
import usb
for dev in usb.core.find(find_all=True):
    print("Device:", dev.filename)
    print("  idVendor: %d (%s)" % (dev.idVendor, hex(dev.idVendor)))
    print("  idProduct: %d (%s)" % (dev.idProduct, hex(dev.idProduct)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for answers, here is snippet that works:

```
def locate_usb():
    import win32file
    drive_list = []
    drivebits = win32file.GetLogicalDrives()
    for d in range(1, 26):
        mask = 1 << d
        if drivebits & mask:
            # here if the drive is at least there
            drname='%c:\\' % chr(ord('A') + d)
            t = win32file.GetDriveType(drname)
            if t == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
                drive_list.append(drname)
    return drive_list
```

taken from https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2006-December/005406.html

Answer (score 1):

but whatever.. someone will look for the answer at some point:

I'm on a mac (osx 10.9)..  I successfully installed libusb with mac ports, but was getting the "no backend available" message.  It's because python can't find the usb dylibs.

You have to add the path to your libusb to your `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`  (e.g. /opt/local/lib  wherever your macport installed it).

As soon I as I added it, pyusb worked fine.

Comment: I just ran into this problem and successfully installed libusb via homebrew:
 `brew install libusb`