# Python: How to search only USB flash drives?

Tags: python, usb, file-search

I have a Python script which is designed to be run from a USB flash drive, and would not work if run from a PC hard drive, so it is safe to assume all copies exist on connected USBs.

I have another script designed to be run from the computer hard drive which seeks these USB scripts and configures them all in a certain way.  Obviously to save time I do not want to search the entire hard drive when I know they are only on USBs.  Is there a way to only search files on a connected USB, skipping searching local drives, through checking drive letters or the like?

Comment: What platform are you on? Linux? Windows? Either way, you're on the right track. First identify the drives, then search them.

Comment: @Hasturkun Based on the usage of "drive letters", I'd guess it's Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some example code to determine the drive type for every active logical drive on Windows, using `ctypes`...

```
import ctypes

# Drive types
DRIVE_UNKNOWN     = 0  # The drive type cannot be determined.
DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR = 1  # The root path is invalid; for example, there is no volume mounted at the specified path.
DRIVE_REMOVABLE   = 2  # The drive has removable media; for example, a floppy drive, thumb drive, or flash card reader.
DRIVE_FIXED       = 3  # The drive has fixed media; for example, a hard disk drive or flash drive.
DRIVE_REMOTE      = 4  # The drive is a remote (network) drive.
DRIVE_CDROM       = 5  # The drive is a CD-ROM drive.
DRIVE_RAMDISK     = 6  # The drive is a RAM disk.

# Map drive types to strings
DRIVE_TYPE_MAP = { DRIVE_UNKNOWN     : 'DRIVE_UNKNOWN',
                   DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR : 'DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR',
                   DRIVE_REMOVABLE   : 'DRIVE_REMOVABLE',
                   DRIVE_FIXED       : 'DRIVE_FIXED',
                   DRIVE_REMOTE      : 'DRIVE_REMOTE',
                   DRIVE_CDROM       : 'DRIVE_CDROM',
                   DRIVE_RAMDISK     : 'DRIVE_RAMDISK'}


# Return list of tuples mapping drive letters to drive types
def get_drive_info():
    result = []
    bitmask = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for i in range(26):
        bit = 2 ** i
        if bit & bitmask:
            drive_letter = '%s:' % chr(65 + i)
            drive_type = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDriveTypeA('%s\\' % drive_letter)
            result.append((drive_letter, drive_type))
    return result


# Test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    drive_info = get_drive_info()
    for drive_letter, drive_type in drive_info:
        print '%s = %s' % (drive_letter, DRIVE_TYPE_MAP[drive_type])
    removable_drives = [drive_letter for drive_letter, drive_type in drive_info if drive_type == DRIVE_REMOVABLE]
    print 'removable_drives = %r' % removable_drives
```

...which prints...

```
C: = DRIVE_FIXED
D: = DRIVE_FIXED
E: = DRIVE_CDROM
removable_drives = []
```

...before inserting a USB stick and...

```
C: = DRIVE_FIXED
D: = DRIVE_FIXED
E: = DRIVE_CDROM
F: = DRIVE_REMOVABLE
removable_drives = ['F:']
```

...afterwards.

Once you've got the list of removable drives, you can simply use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) on each drive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487033/usb-device-identification)

He uses pyUsb for manipulating usb files. Hope this would help.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The linked answer points to `pyusb` which allows you low level USB access. I doubt the asker could use that in this case.