# Program that writes to a certain removable directory (Windows)

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a program for my aquaponics project that will log data. I want to make it so that the python program will create a text file onto my flash drive. I know that on windows, it assigns the directory letter based off the order it was plugged into the PC. Is there a python script that will find the directory letter of my flash drive and write a text file to that location? I am asking because I want to plug my drive into more than 1 PC and I know the letter will be altered each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to search only USB flash drives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028221/python-how-to-search-only-usb-flash-drives)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect inserted USB on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273252/detect-inserted-usb-on-windows)